# django create custom shell command to create app with custom layout

Tags: python, django

i have different layout for my app in my django project,i.e my app layout is as below,

```
myapp/
     models.py/
         __init__.py
     rest_api/
         __init__.py
     services/
         __init__.py
     __init__.py
     admin.py
     apps.py
     models.py
     views.py
     tests.py
```

everytime i create app using './manage.py create app' and then i have to add those directories manually,i want to create an './manage.py .....' command to create app with the layout i have given above,is it possible in django to create an customize command to create custom layout's django app?

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can marked my answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Django allows your to create an custom project structure using template flag. For eg:

```
django-admin.py startproject \
  --template=https://github.com/caktus/django-project-template/zipball/master \
  --extension=py,rst,yml \
  --name=Makefile,gulpfile.js,package.json
  <project_name>
```

https://github.com/caktus/django-project-template

You can use something like this or you can try

```
usage: django-admin startapp [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                             [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                             [--traceback] [--no-color] [--template TEMPLATE]
                             [--extension EXTENSIONS] [--name FILES]
                             name [directory]
```

It also allows for passing a similar template for creating app with custom structure.

Hope this answers your query.